# Comma-formatted STL vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors

I move back and forth between Python and C++ and I often need a nice/quick way to output STL objects to the screen for debugging purposes. I'd like the output to match the output of a comparable Python object, thus I have different templates for vectors, sets, etc...

Is this the best way to go about this?

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T> &A) {
  if(A.empty()) 
    return s << "[]";

  s << "[";
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator itr_penultimate = --A.end();
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator itr = A.begin();

  while(itr != itr_penultimate) {
    s << *itr << ", ";
    itr++;
  }
  return s << *itr << "]";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks fine, but perhaps a more idiomatic option would be to use `ostream_iterator`, or similar constructs with `std::copy`, to avoid the actual loop. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692880/how-to-deal-with-last-comma-when-making-comma-separated-string), for example.  From the first answer:

```
std::ostringstream ss;

std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ", "));
ss << v.back();

std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example or point me in the right direction when you say "ostream_iterator or similar constructs with copy to avoid the actual loop"? Is this the method that uses `std::copy`?

Comment: Added a quote from the link. Just surround with the outside delimiters of choice. :)

Comment: Thanks, just learned about `ostream_iterators` and the copy. I realize you copied the post, but isn't it better to use `std::endl` rather than `"\n"` though?

Comment: Indeed - endl will flush the buffer if the stream is buffered. (Though sometimes that's a reason not to use endl - if I'm writing a bunch of formatted text, I'll prefer \n until I get to the end of the output. So if I were breaking the above after every 80 columns, for instance, I'd probably us "\n" at the end of each line, and endl at the end of the output.)

Comment: @sfjac: Based on one of the comments under that answer, the `-1` is not needed.

Comment: It's needed for the desired formatting but illegal if the container is empty, as is the subsequent call to back, so the empty case is still special.

Comment: --end should be preferred as it will require a reversible container rather than a random access container. With some rather nasty looping you could even make it support forward-iterable-only containers, but since forward_list is the only one, there's probably no point.

Answer (score 8):

The above answer is fine.

The only problem I have is the extra `','` in the output:

```
std::cout << "[ ";
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
std::cout << " ]\n";
```

Generates the output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  ]
                  ^  extra comma
```

You can get around this with some extra work.

```
auto end = data.end();
if (!data.empty()) { --end;}
std::cout << "[ ";
std::copy(data.begin(), end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
if (!data.empty()) {std::cout << *end;}
std::cout << " ]\n";
```

Generates the output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

This is better but it sort of defeats the purpose of using algorithms.

If we had used the loop it would look like this:

```
std::cout << "[";
for(auto loop = data.begin(); loop != data.end(); ++loop)
{
     std::cout << *itr << ", ";
}
std::cout << "]";
```

Of course this has the same problem as the first version of the algorithm above. So if we take that into account you can re-write like this:

```
std::cout << "[";
auto begin = data.begin();
if (!data.empty) {std::cout << *begin;++begin}
for(auto loop = begin; loop != data.end(); ++loop)
{
     std::cout << ", " << *loop;
}
std::cout << "]";
```

Now it works. And because it only use one test on empty is better than the altered algorithm version in my opinion. So what we really need is a version of the output iterator that does the above.

```
template<typename T>
class PrefexOutputIterator
{
    std::ostream&       ostream;
    std::string         prefix;
    bool                first;
    public:

    typedef std::size_t                 difference_type;
    typedef T                           value_type;
    typedef T*                          pointer;
    typedef T                           reference;
    typedef std::output_iterator_tag    iterator_category;

        PrefexOutputIterator(std::ostream& o,std::string const& p = ""): ostream(o), prefix(p), first(true) {}

        PrefexOutputIterator& operator*()       {return *this;}
        PrefexOutputIterator& operator++()      {return *this;}
        PrefexOutputIterator& operator++(int)   {return *this;}

        void operator=(T const& value)
        {
            if (first)      {ostream << value;first = false;}
            else            {ostream << prefix << value;}
        }
};
```

Now we can use this and get the output we want:

```
std::cout << "[";
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), PrefexOutputIterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
std::cout << "]";
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Nowadays though I seem to be using a lot of Json.
So now I use this template librrys: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer

```
using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExport;
using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImport;

std::cout << jsonExport(data) << "\n"; // Serialize the array as json (looks like above)
std::cin  >> jsonImport(data);         // Reads a json array into an array.
```