# Container adaptors

Tags: c++, c++11, collections, c++14

How to improve the functionality, exception safeness and other aspects of the following container adaptors?

Allows to write more generic code (not working for, say, `<set>`):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename container, bool = std::is_const< std::remove_reference_t< container > >::value >
struct consumable_container;

template< typename container >
struct consumable_container< container, false >
{

    consumable_container(container && _container) noexcept
        : container_(std::forward< container >(_container))
    { ; }

    auto
    begin() noexcept
    {
        return std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(container_));
    }

    auto
    end() noexcept
    {
        return std::make_move_iterator(std::end(container_));
    }

private :

    container container_;

};

template< typename container >
struct consumable_container< container, true >
{

    static_assert(!std::is_rvalue_reference< container >::value);

    consumable_container(container && _container) noexcept
        : container_(std::forward< container >(_container))
    { ; }

    auto
    begin() const noexcept
    {
        return std::cbegin(container_);
    }

    auto
    end() const noexcept
    {
        return std::cend(container_);
    }

private :

    container container_;

};

template< typename container >
consumable_container< container >
move_if_not_const(container && _container) noexcept
{
    return std::forward< container >(_container);
}

// some generic code
#include <list>

template< typename container >
auto
transform_to_list(container && _container) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_reference< container >::value || !std::is_const< container >::value);
    std::list< typename std::remove_reference_t< container >::value_type > list_;
    for (auto && value_ : move_if_not_const(std::forward< container >(_container))) {
        list_.push_back(std::forward< decltype(value_) >(value_));
    }
    return list_;
}

// testing data type
#include <iostream>

struct A
{

    A() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    A(A const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A(A &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A(A &&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    A & operator = (A const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }
    A & operator = (A &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }
    A & operator = (A &&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }

};

// testing
#include <deque>
#include <forward_list>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    {
        std::deque< A > const deque_(1);
        std::list< A > ld_ = transform_to_list(deque_);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        std::forward_list< A > forward_list_;
        forward_list_.push_front(A{});
        std::list< A > ls_ = transform_to_list(forward_list_);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        std::vector< A > vector_;
        vector_.push_back(A{});
        std::list< A > lv_ = transform_to_list(std::move(vector_));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Allows to enumerate elements in reverse order:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template< typename container >
struct reversed_container
{

    reversed_container(container && _container) noexcept
        : container_(std::forward< container >(_container))
    { ; }

    auto
    begin() noexcept
    {
        return std::rbegin(container_);
    }

    auto
    end() noexcept
    {
        return std::rend(container_);
    }

private :

    container container_;

};

template< typename container >
reversed_container< container >
reverse(container && _container) noexcept
{
    return std::forward< container >(_container);
}

// testing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    std::vector< int > vector_({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    // using
    for (int i : reverse(vector_)) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Allows to print list of elements with delimiter (without trailing delimiter):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template< typename container >
struct head_container
{

    head_container(container && _container) noexcept
        : container_(std::forward< container >(_container))
    { ; }

    auto
    begin() noexcept
    {
        return std::begin(container_);
    }

    auto
    end() noexcept
    {
        auto last = std::end(container_);
        if (last == std::begin(container_)) {
            return last;
        } else {
            return std::prev(last);
        }
    }

private :

    container container_;

};

template< typename container >
head_container< container >
head(container && _container) noexcept
{
    return std::forward< container >(_container);
}

// testing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    std::vector< int > vector_({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    // using
    if (!vector_.empty()) {
        for (int i : head(vector_)) {
            std::cout << i << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << vector_.back() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Allows to treat first element in special way:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template< typename container >
struct tail_container
{

    tail_container(container && _container) noexcept
        : container_(std::forward< container >(_container))
    { ; }

    auto
    begin() noexcept
    {
        auto first = std::begin(container_);
        if (first == std::end(container_)) {
            return first;
        } else {
            return std::next(first);
        }
    }

    auto
    end() noexcept
    {
        return std::end(container_);
    }

private :

    container container_;

};

template< typename container >
tail_container< container >
tail(container && _container) noexcept
{
    return std::forward< container >(_container);
}

// testing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    std::vector< int > vector_({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    // using
    if (!vector_.empty()) {
        for (int i : tail(vector_)) {
            vector_.front() += i;
        }
        std::cout << vector_.front() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can't say I see the utility here. All this is provided by the standard library (just using a different syntax). So it seems you are adding a layer of abstraction that separates the developer from the class without providing any benefits.

Comment: @LokiAstari What is the different syntax? Did you mean the use of iterators itself?

Comment: `transform_to_list()` available via constructor and iterators. `reverse()` is available by directly calling `rbegin() and `rend()` or using a `range` adapter from boost. Your `head()` and tail is better adapted using an iterator adapter see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430892/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari All that you said looks as much more verbose approach. The purpose of adaptors is to reduce the verbosity of user code. I always can write a plenty of code with iterators, but don't want.

Comment: @LokiAstari Syntactic sugar are the salt of this adaptors.

Answer (score 2):

> The point of the code is to reduce verbosity:

Lets examine that:

```
std::list< A > ls_ = transform_to_list(forward_list_);

// Using iterators.
std::list< A > ls_(begin(forward_list_), end(forward_list_));

// Don't think its that verbose.
// Not only does it work with list but it also works with every other container.
```

Reverse is already done:

```
for (int i : reverse(vector_)) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

// Or we can use the standard library (or probably future extensions)
// Slightly longer but its properly namespaced so that's understandable.
for (auto i : boost::adaptors::reverse(vector_))
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

And my favorite:

```
if (!vector_.empty()) {
    for (int i : head(vector_)) {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << vector_.back() << std::endl;
}

// Or with a specialized iterator.
// Which definitely seems shorter and less verbose.
std::copy(std::begin(vector_), std::end(vector_), PrefexOutputIterator(std::cout, ","));
```

#### Code Review

I don't see anything wrong (or that needs improving) with your code. Its nice and clean (some comments may hep the less experienced read the code). But overall it looks fine.

#### Goal of Code

I don't agree that the code achieves its goals (reduced verbosity of user code). I also think it makes boilerplate code more likely in user code (and boilerplate is bad as it tends to be cut and paste rather than written).

```
if (!vector_.empty()) {
    for (int i : head(vector_)) {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << vector_.back() << std::endl;
}
```

Forcing your user to write a whole section of code, rather than simplifying the task of writing code is where you fail.

I also think you need to understand where C++ has been going over the last 6->8 years. This is towards the use of ranges (with iterators as the underlying model used as the building block for ranges).

Comment: WRT `transform_to_list`: function steal the container's values, if container is not `const`-qualified. It is also possible to achieve the same functionality by means of simple overloading (for `const &`, `&` and `&&`: two last should be stealed via `std::make_move_iterator`). In that case it will be too verbose.

Comment: @Orient: Sorry. I disagree.

Comment: WRT `std::copy(beg, end, std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, ", "));` there is **unneeded** trailing comma. `if (beg != end) { std::copy(beg, std::prev(end), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, ", ")); if (beg != std::prev(end)) { std::cout << *std::prev(end); } }` is the solution, but again: too verbose at my mind.

Comment: Another note is: it is hard to make custom `PrefexOutputIterator` for specific purposes (not only for output text into stream with delimiters).

Comment: You can't disagree with my intentions regarding my own code :). It is not your prerogative. I can make mistake, but I have my free will. You can't decide something instead of me with respect to my intentions. It is nonsense and absurdity if not.

Comment: It's not hard to make `PrefexOutputIterator` I provide the link to show its easy.

Comment: Where is the link? I see only blue text.

Comment: I can disagree that you have achieved your objectives. You seem to be trying to solve problems that don't exist. That is the point of code review. If one of my developeres did this I would reject the code and explain (as I have done above) that there are better ways to achieve the same goals without adding a huge maintenance burden to the project (as there are standard ways to do it).

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430892/14065 and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/30181/507

Comment: Its your code. Feel free to ignore my ramblings. But you asked for my opinion don't get upset when I point out the flaws I see.

Comment: And what is your conclusion? What is less wordy? Above proposal or *to subclass the iterator each time* (note, that I can't make templated subclass into the function body)?

Comment: This discussion is useful for me.

Comment: Why would I sub class the iterator? Comments are not a good place to ask such broad open question. Add to your question a concrete example if were you think your code becomes more readable and I will happily look at to see if I think it solves an existing problem.

Comment: OK, there is a point of completely mutual misunderstanding. (The first adaptor is `move_if_not_const` not `transform_to_list`, the later is example how to use in some generic code).